# Как убрать висячий внешний отступ?

Tags: html, css, margin

Подскажите пожалуйста, как убрать висячий внешний отступ? У меня есть два блока (.main__form и .main__item). Второй (.main__item) из этих двух блоков скрыт с помощью display: none, но почему-то у первого (.main__form) все равно появляется нижний внешний отступ. Если удалить из кода скрытый блок, то и внешний отступ пропадает. Как быть? Просто, я хочу чтобы отступ появлялся тогда, когда второй блок был видимым, а не просто так висел.

[image: Скрин]

Comment: добавьте html и css

Comment: Потому что `display` на `:not` не влияет. Нода есть, значит элемент не последний, значит класс отработает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема, не совсем там где вы ищите, хотя на скрине, она присутствует

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Что в переводе на человеческий - нижний внешний отступ у main_form которая не является последним дочерним элементом, т.е. ровно Ваша ситуация.

Я предлагаю если блоков всегда 2, то добавлять верхний отступ к нижнему, тогда он будет появляться вместе с блоком и исчезать с ним же.

```css
.main__form:not(:last-child){
  margin-bottom: 0; /* можно убрать снизу */
}

.main__item{
  margin-top: 30px; /* можно добавить свеху */
  /*display: none*/
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form class="main__form">
    <button>Ok</button>
  </form>
  <form class="main__item">
    <button>Ok</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: А ответ то в чём состоит? Это больше раздутый комментарий)

Comment: Спасибо, за конструктив, добавил свое виденье решения.

Comment: @DaniilLoban, да спасибо) Что-то сразу в голову не пришло)

Comment: @НикитаГребенкин пожалуйста, [что делать с ответами](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @DaniilLoban Да, теперь это нормальный ответ 